# How do I avoid expanding folded regions when I invoke the code formatter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, code-formatting, code-folding

As you know, Delphi 2010 has built-in code formatting. However, formatting unfolds all folded code blocks. Any ideas how to fix it? This "feature" is particularly annoying for me and I was really astonished when I couldn't find any mention of this problem. What I've tried:

- Searching for alternative, e.g., GExperts have code formatter plugin, but it also unfolds code blocks.
- Tried to write a macro for GExperts: Ctrl+D(format code) -> various code folding/unfolding shortcuts, but couldn't manage to make it respect all folded/unfolded block structures.
- Write a CnWizards script, but could't find a code folding example.

I would be really grateful for any idea/hint.

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around it is to not format the entire file at once, but to select a portion, and format that.

As long as you don't select a region, the expand-state of all regions remains untouched.

Formatting an entire file at once is usually not really a good idea anyway, because the formatter doesn't "understand" what it's doing. I always inspect all changes that it makes, and that's easier when there are no changes outside of the area that's visible.

Comment: Many thanks for a reply. However, selecting a portion of text and then formatting it still unfolds other blocks of code in Delphi 2010. The same for GExperts code formatter. Which version of Delphi does it work for?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is really old, but as it was mentioned here:

[How to preserve code folding when formatting source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566156/how-to-preserve-code-folding-when-formatting-source/29591220#29591220)

and there is no answer, I thought I could answer both, here is the answer I posted there:

What you can do is create regions and disable code folding, format code and then reenable the code folding.

To create code regions do:

```
{$REGION 'Optional text that appears when the code block is folded'} 
// code 
{$ENDREGION}
```

To toggle code folding option, press Ctrl+Shift K+O.

so, put your code into regions, fold what you want, press Ctrl+Shift K+O to disable the folding, format by pressing Ctrl+D then press Ctrl+Shift K+O again to re enable the folding.

When you re enable the folding, what was folded with a region is going to stay folded.

information source: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Code_Folding

I hope this helps you.