# How do I keep Delphi from automatically expanding folded code regions?

Tags: delphi, code-formatting, delphi-xe4, code-folding

I widely use `{$Regions}` in my units, but sometimes the VCL editor takes annoying decisions to automatically expand all regions. Is there any way to tell the editor not
to expand regions that are collapsed unless I explicity do this by clicking on the `+` button?

---

Update from comments:

Unfolding occurs,

1. with nested procs/funcs. Introducing a new nested "procedure" header. As soon as you type the 'p' character, all other nested procs/funcs are unfolded. This occurss also if, for instance, by mistake, you delete the "end" of any nested proc/func (or anything of the kind).
2. with regions. If you start a comment with "{", the Region immediately below is unfolded. Starting a comment with "(*" provoques all Regions below to be unfolded and same applies to all procs/funcs under those Regions.

Comment: [Delphi code format & folding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691231/delphi-code-format-folding)

Comment: Can you elaborate on precisely what you mean by "sometimes"

Comment: @David. For example, any time I make any change the Editor expands all nested procedures. It also expands all folded types when changing any part of the code.

Comment: Doesn't do that here

Comment: @David. What's your version? Mine is XE4 and it certanly does... Write a procedure with nested procedures/functions into it. Fold all nested procedures/functions and then make any change on the code. You'll see the thing happening.

Comment: Nope, I don't see that. If I were you I'd include a sample program that can be used to demonstrate what you encounter.

Comment: Do you happen to have any add-ins installed? Perhaps you have something configured to automatically reformat your code, and it gets triggered when the code is changed, prompting it to rewrite the contents of the editor. The rewrite causes the folded regions to expand, but you don't notice any other difference because your code is otherwise already formatted.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Please include a sample *compilable* code unit that we can use to demonstrate this issue.

Comment: @David. Unfolding occurs, (1) with nested procs/funcs. Introducing a new nested "procedure" header. As soon as you type the 'p' character, all other nested procs/funcs are unfolded. This occurss also if, for instance, by mistake, you delete the "end" of any nested proc/func (or anything of the kind). (2) with regions. If you start a comment with "{", the Region immediately below is unfolded. Starting a comment with "(*" provoques all Regions below to be unfolded and same applies to all procs/funcs under those Regions. I'm attaching a working sample in the next comment.

Comment: Now you are getting there with some hard details. Good. But it needs to be in a question edit.

Comment: @David. What you mean with "needs to be a question edit"?

Comment: Edit the question and add the details to the question. The question should have all the information.

Comment: @Rob. I have `GExperts`. I couldn't find no such configuration in GExperts.

Comment: What David means by "edit the question" is to click the link labeled 'edit' that appears under the tags in your question. (He could have linked to it by asking you to [edit] your question as well.) Adding the information to your question means that everyone can see that information without wading through all of these comments trying to locate it. Put details into the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of the problems of Delphi whis is present athleast since Delphi XE if not even from older versions and still hasn't been fixed.

The reason why code gets automaticaly unfolded is the fact that as soon as Error Insight system detects any syntax error in your unit it treats all the code below that poiunt as non-valid and thus expans all folded code below that point.

So far the only way that I know to avoid this is to disable the Error Insight. But that means you won't be warned about any potentional syntax errors untill you try to compile your program.

But I seriously hope Embarcadero will go and fix this soon as it makeswhole code folding system to be useless unles you have Error Insight disabled as you spend more time folding the autoexpanded code again that writing any new code.

EDIT: Steps to reproduce this (one way of reproducing it)

Create new application

Create two new even handlers for OnCreate and OnClose for your form or any two other methods.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  //
end;
```

In case if you created even handlers make sure there is athleast some code in the lowest handler metrhod or athleast one commented line so that optimizer doesent automatically remove the "empy" event handler.

Now in top event handler write "Form." and you will se how bottom event handler will be automatically expanded.

You will see that at this point delphi desent even know when or where current method code block in which syntax error has been detected ends. And this also makes it imposible to properly detect any code blocks below that point.

Comment: No one seems to be able to reproduce this problem in the way the poster here is describing. If you have steps to do so, can you provide them?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the steps for one scenario of how to reproduce this problem. But the problem is that this happens in multiple different scenarios.

Comment: @Silver. Thanks for your answer. You have been very straight an objective. I allready figured out that this is an issue for Embarcadero to resolve. I hope this is fixed in the last version. I think this behavoir is not acceptable as at some extent, makes the code folding useless. To Ken and David, I thank for your interest, but with all due respect, it should be more usefull if you sticked with the original question: "How do I keep Delphi from automatically expanding folded code regions?", instead of trying to reproduce the behavoir.