# How to preserve code folding when formatting source

Tags: delphi, ide, code-folding, toolsapi

See also this question: [How do I avoid expanding folded regions when I invoke the code formatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19691231/62576)

This is not a dupe, because I'm interested in solving the problem using the ToolsApi.

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> the code formats nicely <sup>(mostly)</sup>.
But all my folded code sections get unfolded.
Is there a way to keep these sections folded.

If not, is it possible to save the code folding info prior to formatting, so I can restore it later?
I'm thinking of writing IDE-addin using the Open Tools api.
I'm using XE7, but this problem exists in all versions that have source formatting.

Possible scenario's involve:

- Record and replay code foldings (hook `elide` calls).
- Only allow formatting to work on the current block (redefine the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> action).

Comment: I'm guessing this will involve hooking the `elide` calls to built a list of the folded blocks and than walking the source in the editor to restore those blocks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19691231/62576

Comment: Also consider what happens if the formatting changes line breaks within the code. So just saving the positions/lengths of folded code is not enough, if you don't take into account that they might change value during formatting.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create regions and disable code folding, format code and then reenable the code folding.

To create code regions do:

```
{$REGION 'Optional text that appears when the code block is folded'} 
// code 
{$ENDREGION}
```

To toggle code folding option, press Ctrl+Shift K+O.

so, put your code into regions, fold what you want, press Ctrl+Shift K+O to disable the folding, format by pressing Ctrl+D then press Ctrl+Shift K+O again to re enable the folding.

When you re enable the folding, what was folded with a region is going to stay folded.

information source: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Code_Folding

I hope this helps you.